zoom sdk for meetings. download from the site or via npm?
I want to add to the application(NextJS) the ability to call via zoom directly on my website, "inserting" zoom into my page, with the ability to receive data and assign calls through the API.
I am following as per their guide:

https://developers.zoom.us/docs/meeting-sdk/create/#step-4-download-the-sdk

The question is that I don’t understand what to do at step 4, download the file (I understand correctly that the OS means the one on which the site is “running”, well, that is, Linux as a rule?) or use the library, which is used in almost all tutorials -

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@zoomus/websdk

Please tell me, otherwise I'm confused at this stage. Thanks a lot!
